# .click event and checkboxes

Tags: jquery

In my script I'm using .click event. When I click my checkbox, value is sending, but there isn't tick in it. So using jquery I "clicked" checkbox, but there isn't working. There is the code:

```
$(".checkinput").click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id')
var dumpthis = $(this);
var data = "id=" + id;
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "change_achievement.php",
 data: data,
 success: function()
 {
   if(dumpthis.attr('checked')
{
 dumpthis.attr('checked', true);
}
else
{
 dumpthis.attr('checked', false);
}
 }
});

return false;
});
```

Comment: Maybe the change event would be better?

Comment: not sure if this was a typo or got lost in the edit. but your missing a )  on this line:  if(dumpthis.attr('checked')

Answer (score 1):

You are returning false at the end of the handler obviously the checkbox will never be checked. Remove the statement `return false;` from your click handler.

So the handler should now look like:

```
$(".checkinput").click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var dumpthis = $(this);
    var data = "id=" + id;
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "change_achievement.php",
     data: data,
     success: function()
     {
        if(dumpthis.attr('checked')
                {
                 dumpthis.attr('checked', true);
                }
                else
                {
                 dumpthis.attr('checked', false);
                }
     }
    });
        //######THE STATEMENT BELOW SHOULD BE COMMENTED FOR THE CHECKBOX TO WORK
    //return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are returning false in the end of your click() handler, this stops the event to effect your checkbox. Try return true; to see if it can solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `$(".checkinput").change()`...